# Connect to Redis Docker container from a none docker app in a remote server

Tags: docker, redis

**Goal:** Connect to Redis via an app from a remote server.

**Problem:** I don't know the exact syntax of a Redis container creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose ports from docker to the world.

```
docker run --name some-redis -d -p 6379:6379 redis
```

But you need to be carefuly if you doing this on public IP,
so is better to attach a config file with security enabled.

```
docker run --name some-redis -d -p 6379:6379 \
     -v /path/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf \ 
     redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind Redis container on host port & connect from the remote server using "REDIS_HOST:REDIS_HOST_PORT".

```
docker run -d --name redis -v <data-dir>:/data -p 6379:6379 redis
```

You should be able to connect to redis now from remote app server on REDIS_HOST and port 6379.

PS - The DNS/IP address of the Redis host should not change.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports